# Can't override preference using PhoneGap Build (order in generated config.xml is wrong)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, statusbar

I am using `cordova-plugin-statusbar` to customize the appearance of my app's statusbar on iOS. Specifically, I want to change the value of `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` to false, so I include the following line in my `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

This works great when I test using a local XCode build. When I build on PhoneGap Build, however, the default setting for this value (which is `true`) is not overridden.

After considerable head-scratching, I noticed that the order of the preferences in `config.xml` is different in the one generated by PhoneGap. In my local build, the following lines from the plugin's `plugin.xml` are included *before* the line overriding the setting:

`<feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />`

In the `config.xml` generated by PhoneGap, however, these lines appear at the very end of the file. I am guessing that "last write wins" and thus the default value is overwriting my custom preference.

Is there some way for me to influence this or is it just a PhoneGap Build bug?

Comment: Any way you can build using Xcode? You can modify the plist to hide the status bar.

Comment: Actually you can override the plist settings using the `config-file tag`. I know I can hide the status bar on startup and then configure it using JavaScript. I'll probably end up doing this as a workaround but I would like to undertand why doing it the "right" way is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matthew,
Okay. Thanks for loading your `config.xml`. I did read it. I'm not sure you need the extension for `NSAppTransportSecurity`. Take them out for now, but save them, just in case.

Here is some more stuff to help clarify.

#### plugins

- versions of the latest plugins with new spelling; make sure to *source=npm*
- [Plugins Release: June 22, 2015](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/06/22/plugins-release.html)

#### white-list

- The following blog post corrects misconceptions and misinformation about the white-list, the plugin and CSP. Raymond confesses to making mistake, luckily not may people have made those mistakes. I'm almost sure you have not.
- [Important information about Cordova 5](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5)

In addition, read [the documentation with the plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) (near the top), and not just the [*white-list guide*](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements).

You may need to add:

- `<allow-navigation (..)>`
- `<allow-intent (..)>`

Let me know how it goes. Ohh, and let me see your final `config.xml`. TIA

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a newer version of `cordova-plugin-statusbar` than the one listed on the page you reference (1.0.1 vs. 1.0.0). The `plugin.xml` contains the following the `feature` tag and default `preference` tags that are causing the problem. I'll make the changes you suggest but I still don't understand how that will fix the issue. Since the plugin has `preference` tags that PhoneGap Build places after my `preference` tags, how do I prevent them from overriding my desired settings?

Comment: I've been as clear as I can on this. But I'll try again. You did NOT set your version for your compiler. So you have cascading errors. You are using deprecated items, this is causing confusing. On the `white-list` stuff, when you fix the other issues, the `white-list` MAY popup as an issue.  Here is a definition for the word **[cascading](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cascade)** - noun #2 & #4, verb #3 -- The thing in your mind about overriding each other is a red herring, put there from the cascading errors. Just fix your base. We will get things working. I'm not going anywhere.

Comment: You say I should set my compiler version because I am using deprecated items. Can you spell this out for me? Namely:

1) Which version of the compiler _should_ I be using? PhoneGap Build tells me it is using `5.2.0` which looks to me like a recent version.
2) Which deprecated items am I using? In your original answer you said I shouldn't use `<feature>` tags, but that string doesn't occur anywhere in my `config.xml`.
3) Why does the use of the default compiler on PhoneGap Build (i.e. `5.2.0`) cause deprecated items to be used in my app?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MatthewGertner, thanks for the direct question. We are making great progress. ON #1, the version you use is not important. It is important you you do use THE version field. If you do NOT, the next time you compile you MAY get cascading errors. Which means we start this process over again _OR_ you get lucky and it is a simple fix. Using a version insure you program will work the next time you compile - especially from scratch.

Comment: ON #2, from you original post, it appears you were saying that `<feature>` was being using in the plugin. This is a red flag. First, there is no reason for you to look inside of the `plugin.xml`, unless the author asks you to. If you are looking that deep into the plugin, then author has made some fundamental errors. If the steps we are taking, fix your issue, then there is no harm. If the steps we are taking, do *not* fix your issue, then there is something else -- but looking in `plugin.xml` is a red herring for most developers.

Comment: I wasn't really looking into the `plugin.xml` but rather the generated `config.xml`. Anyway it sounds like I'll have to wait for the plugin author to update it. In the meantime, I'll implement a workaround.

Comment: To be clear ON #2, that was my mistake. I read (apparently in error) you had added `<feature>` in you config.xml. My mistake. ON #3, the default compiler does **not cause** deprecated items to be used. The default compiler makes deprecated items fail in unpredictable manners. In a message from another person that does troubleshooting on forums daily (like i do), that other person stated, "(the sudden jump in versoin) caused the sudden need of splashscreen and whitelist plugins and additional whitelisting specifications (...) causing log file error messages about 'Class ***.java'."

Comment: IN summation, I apologize for any confusion. The back to back unannounced changes in Cordova has caught many people. Helping people fixing them has been frustrating and tiresome. I hope I've done you right and your issue is solve. :-)

Comment: Well I think you confirmed that I'm not missing anything obvious. There's a straightforward workaround I can implement for now, and I'll wait for the statusbar plugin folks to fix their config. In the meantime I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew
your conclusions are incorrect. The order may make a difference, but this is only because you are using a deprecated item.

Here is what you need to know.

1. You need to source all you plugins from NPM from now on - starting last week.
2. You need to remove ALL references about `<feature (...)>` - see below.
3. You should start using version for your compiler and plugins - see below.
4. You should post your `config.xml` before you make any changes, just in case there are other issues.

All the solutions needed for this fix are in one place:
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
The answers cover Cordova/Phonegap both CLI and SDK, as well as Phonegap Build.

### On 1.

From the above reference you have hit

> **11. You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**
>
> The rules regarding sourcing your plugins can be rather confusing. The best thing to do is read the blog posts - below. Developers that use CLI can source from github, again see the blog post.

NEW NEW [Cordova npm search page](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)

- [Cordova Plugins Registry becomes immutable](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/08/CPR-readonly.html) 2015/09/08
- [Plugins Release and Moving plugins to npm](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html) 2015/04/21

### On 2.

This is brand new, I have not had time to add it to the FAQ

`<feature>` tags are deprecated. That means they are no longer used.
You can [read about it here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_features.md.html#Features)

#### I QUOTE

> Aside from the `debug-server` feature, the `<feature>` tag is essentially deprecated on *PhoneGap Build* since *PhoneGap APIs* were pluginized. Permissions are now generally managed by individual plugins, and application manifests and permissions can be modified directly using the [config-file element](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html). However for backwards-compatibility, they are still supported and map to device permissions on Android and Windows Phone 8:

In other words, you have a duplicate configuration, and it is doing nothing. Take it out.

### On 3.

From the above reference you have hit

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all: **(NOTE: Holly has not had time to update the article since the move to NPM, use the NPM names, not the names she is using.)**
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

I want to repart that part about *cascading errors*. You and many, many people are at that stage now. In part because of the change of plugin servers (now on NPM) AND because the white-list restrictions have unprepared people scrambling. This part is very very important. Set your verisons now, and in the future upgrade on your time, budget and terms, NOT at the whims of the Cordova team.

### On 4.

Please post your `config.xml`. I've done this dozens of times and I always pay the price, when people don't post. Thanks.

One last thing, the `white-list` requirement. I don't know if you need to use the internet, but if you do read #10 on that FAQ.

Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks, @JesseMonroy650. You can see my `config.xml` here: https://gist.github.com/matthewgertner/7ed0fb5f9c6882c7f197. I'm using the latest `cordova-plugin-statusbar` which includes the `feature` tags in its `plugin.xml`, so I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'll read your FAQ carefully and see if I can figure it out.