# Whitelisting error on Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, whitelist

I am having a weird whitelist error using phonegap/cordova

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp',
                     ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngStorage',
                      'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.sortable', 'ui.utils', 'ui.calendar','ui.select2',
                      'com.2fdevs.videogular',
                      'googlechart',
                      'monospaced.elastic',
                      'ngImgCrop',
                      'anguFixedHeaderTable',
                      'toggle-switch',
                      'ngFileUpload',
                      'textAngular'],
                      function ($compileProvider) {
                        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|webcal|mailto):/);
                      }
 );
```

When I have this aHrefSanitizationWhitelist, I cannot get to links like 
      Link name 
Links like this work fine
      Link name

If I comment out

```
    function ($compileProvider) {
                        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|webcal|mailto):/);
```

The links work fine.

The problem is the app uses webcal and when I comment out those lines it breaks the web calendar functionality.

in my config.xml file, I have the following:

```
   <access origin="*" />
```

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: `white-list` is the name of the game. The two just before you, and there are dozens more in the stack. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130559/cordova-plugin-whitelist-working-on-android-but-not-ios-phonegap-build  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129008/cant-override-preference-using-phonegap-build-order-in-generated-config-xml-is

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your config.xml file

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Comment: You may need CSP also.